# Graph class where Hamiltonian Path is polynomial and Path cover is NP-complete?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, hamiltonian-path

Path cover asks, what is the minimal number k such that G can be covered by k vertex-disjoint paths. (Path cover of G has size 1 if and only if G has a Hamiltonian path).

Is there a graph class (especially, I am looking for hereditary one), where Hamiltonian path problem can be solved in polynomial time but deciding the size of path cover is NP-hard? Or is there any reason why such class does not exist?

Comment: Silly answer: the class of graphs with no Hamiltonian path :)

Comment: Is it obvious why path cover is still NP-hard? @MishaLavrov

Comment: @MathieuRundström Maybe not completely obvious - but if you take any graph $G$ and add an isolated vertex, you get a graph with no Hamiltonian path for which the path cover problem is equivalent to the path cover for $G$.